# Drawing a Curly Brace in pure Java code using Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

Can I draw a curly brace in java using only one curve. I have tried doing it by using CubicCurve2D, but I have drawn 2 curves and then joined them to get a curly brace.

Comment: One curve, I doubt it, two most likely

Comment: Even I had this confusion, that's why I asked. I have already drawn a brace using two curves

Comment: How is your brace defined? Their look varies greatly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;

public class CurlyBrace extends Frame{

    int preX, preY;
    CubicCurve2D shape;
   public CurlyBrace(){
      super("Java AWT Examples");
      prepareGUI();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      CurlyBrace  awtGraphicsDemo = new CurlyBrace();  
      awtGraphicsDemo.setVisible(true);
   }

   private void prepareGUI(){
      setSize(400,400);
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      }); 
   }    

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
       shape = new CubicCurve2D.Float();

      shape.setCurve(150F,100F,200F,90F,130F,200F,190F,220F);
      CubicCurve2D shape2 = new CubicCurve2D.Float();
      shape2.setCurve(190F,220F,140F,230F,190F,350F,150F,340F);

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
      g2.draw (shape);
      g2.draw (shape2);
      Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
      g2.setFont(font);

   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON) for this to look less ugly ;)